# Can the size of a COM queue cause a stack overflow?

Tags: c++, com, com-interop

I guess this can only happen in an STA setting due to the fact that all COM calls are handled by a single thread.
I have a test scenario with a .NET application making a COM call to a C++ component which calls a remote COM component. (I have the code of all components)
This .NET application starts a few hundred Tasks. Each Tasks does between 3 and 5 COM calls, each of them doing at least one more COM call to the remote component.
So we have a lot of COM calls.

What happens is that after a while this program runs into a stack overflow error although there is no recursion happening on any level.
In the debugger I can see that the thread causing the exception has all the COM calls waiting to be processed queued up. I can see that quite clearly because it starts at the COM call to the native component and stops at the COM call to the remote component.

Does this even make sense?
Can too many COM calls cause a stack overflow?
Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: "COM calls are handled by a single thread" is an incorrect statement. I suggest you (re)read official doc in details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/single-threaded-apartments . That being said, it's possible that you have stack overflow if calls or data stack somewhere, COM or not COM. So the question is what stacks and why does it stack? The most probable cause if something stacks is because some component at an end doesn't answer calls fast enough. Also, are your components .exe (out of proc) or .dll (inproc)? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: My guess - you spawn new tasks in response to window messages, e.g. `WM_TIMER`. An out-of-apartment COM call spins up a message pump, which may dequeue and dispatch those messages. So you make a new COM call from inside the first one - that call spins its own message pump, which may dispatch a message that starts a new task...